# Why is my code generating different results

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am learning automation through Selenium (using Java programming language), and I am working on a test case. The last step in my case involves checking for the presence of a button an a page, by using `findElement.By.xpath`, and I have two versions of the step. With either version, my entire test case passes. However, the two versions each generate a different result by themselves. If I use the first version, with the int, I get "Write review button' does not exist" result. If I use the second version with the Boolean, I get "Write review button' exists!"
Since the test case passes, and with the second version generating the 'button exists' result, the problem cannot be with the xpath, so the issue with the second version getting the wrong result must be in the logic, yet I cannot tell what it is.

I tried rerunning the case multiple times to see if the problem is a glitch, but same result. I tried finding similar problems online, but cannot find anything that shows exactly how my problem is wrong.

```
int i = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='comments_advices']")).size();
if (i > 0)  { System.out.println("'Write review button' exists!"); }
else        { System.out.println("'Write review button' does not exist :( ");
```

}

```
boolean reviewButtonPresent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='comments_advices']")).size() > 0;
if (reviewButtonPresent = true) { System.out.println("'Write review button' exists!"); }
else { System.out.println("'Write review button' does not exist :( "); }
```

Comment: **reviewButtonPresent = true** you meant **==** right? And note, when checking for booleans, just go `if (someCondition)` and avoid that == true or == false stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The two instances of code you have are essentially the same and I see no reason for them to perform differently. My guess is that it's a timing issue. To make it behave more consistently, I would add a wait for the review button to appear. Since the button may not be there at times, it will throw a timeout exception so you will need to catch that to have a clean pass/fail for each run. To do this, I would use the function below that returns a boolean based on whether the element exists or not after waiting.

```
public static boolean elementExists(By locator, int timeout)
{
    try
    {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The above method tests for the "presence" of the element which means, does it exist in the DOM? If you want to make sure that it's actually visible (and not just present), you will want to change `.presenceOfElementLocated()` to `.visibilityOfElementLocated()`.

Since you are new to Selenium, I would also recommend that you use a common library to do your validations like JUnit or TestNG. This will keep you from having to write your own custom code for validations and go through the process of finding bugs in your own custom code. Using JUnit, you would use

```
Assert.assertTrue("Verify the review button exists", elementExists(By.xpath("//ul[@class='comments_advices']"), 10));
```

See the [JUnit docs](https://junit.org/junit5/).

Comment: thank you for the analysis. Since you say the two instances are essentially the same, do you see any errors in the code?

Comment: No, I don't see any errors... places for improvement, but no errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are some **differences** between the two blocks of code.

---

Apparently your first code block is logically correct which is as follows:

- Code:

  ```
  int i = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='comments_advices']")).size();
  if (i > 0)  
      System.out.println("'Write review button' exists!"); 
  else
      System.out.println("'Write review button' does not exist :( ");
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  Write review button' does not exist
  ```

But it's not perfect, which I will explain later in this discussion.

---

Your second code block is a bit *deceptive* as it contains two logical operators in the same line and you have left it to the compiler to decide the [Operator Precedence](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html) which is a clear deviation from the best practices. Possibly you were lucky as **`>`** had more precedence then **`=`** as in:

```
boolean reviewButtonPresent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='comments_advices']")).size() > 0;
```

---

### Solution

Ideally you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()`.
- Evalute the `size()` through a `if()`
- Sample Code:

  ```
  if (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[@class='comments_advices']"))).size()>0) 
      System.out.println("'Write review button' exists!"); 
  else 
      System.out.println("'Write review button' does not exist :( ");
  ```

---

### Outro

[**`Operator Precedence`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html):

> The operators in the following table are listed according to their precedence order. The closer to the top of the table an operator appears, the higher its precedence. Operators with higher precedence are evaluated before operators with relatively lower precedence. Operators on the same line have equal precedence. When operators of equal precedence appear in the same expression, a rule must govern which is evaluated first. All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right; assignment operators are evaluated right to left.

[image: OperatorPrecedence]

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything different than OP's except you put the first line inside the `if`. You added a wait, which I already covered, but the OP is asking about presence not visibility. Then you posted a ton of stuff about operator precedence which has nothing to do with this question. So what does your answer add?